# Local Java Applet is blocked

Tags: java, applet

I try to get a local applet running on a local HTML page. I have put the file on the exception list as

file:///c:/work/test.html

I also tried simple things like

file://

I have checked that the Java configuration is from the same version as the Java plugin. The first version 1.8.0_25-b18 I took from the configuration tool and its button "Info". The other from the Java console. The plugin version is 11.25.2.18.

So far nothing worked. I always get an error message telling me (in German) that my security settings prevent the application of local applets.

What now?

Answer (score 0):

Go to java settings in Control Panel -> Java -> Security Tab and make sure that Enable Java content in browser is on and your security level is not too high - that was a problem when I was testing the applet.

In addition to this as far as I know in Java 8 security settings requires applet to be signed., so no more unsigned and self signed, I am still on 7 + last time I had to do with applets was about a year ago.